# R style data-axis buffer in matplotlib

Tags: python, r, matplotlib, plot

R plots automatically set the x and y limits to put some space between the data and the axes. I was wondering if there is a way for matplotlib to do the same automatically. If not, is there a good formula or 'rule of thumb' for how R sets its axis limits?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at `?par` for the parameter `xaxs`:

> The style of axis interval calculation to be used for the x-axis. Possible values are "r", "i", "e", "s", "d". The styles are generally controlled by the range of data or xlim, if given.
>   **Style "r" (regular) first extends the data range by 4 percent at each end and then finds an axis with pretty labels that fits within the extended range.**

So if we try this out:

```
par(xaxs="r")       #The default  
plot(1:10, 1:10)
```

[image]

We can actually demonstrate that it's +/- 4% of the range on each side:

```
abline(v=1-(diff(range(1:10)))*0.04, col="red")
abline(v=10+(diff(range(1:10)))*0.04, col="red")
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

In matplotlib you can achieve this by setting the [`margins`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html?highlight=xlim#matplotlib.axes.Axes.margins)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.margins(0.04)
data = range(1, 11) 
ax.plot(data, 'wo') 
plt.savefig('margins.png')
```

[image: margins]

However, it doesn't seems, that there is an rc parameter to get this automatically.

**Update 4/2013**

The possibility to add an rc param for the margins is now in matplotlib [master](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/1908) 
(Thanks @tcaswell).
So it should work with the next matplotlib release (current release is 1.2.1).

Comment: This is the right answer. Not sure why the other answer was chosen since the question was asking about Python's matplotlib and not R's plot() (R was just used as a comparison).